# Plotting a logarithmic scale, and including zero?

Tags: javascript, math, graph

I am wanting to draw a graph, with values on a logarithmic scale, such that (assuming JS here) Math.pow(10,x). The range of numbers can be any positive values ranging from zero to n. The challenge I am finding is dealing with zero, since 10^0 is 1. I have tried the following, but I am sure there is a better way to approach this:

```
var range = [0, 100];

exponentAdjust = 0;

if (range[0] < 1 && range[0] > 0) {
   exponentAdjust = Math.log10(range[0]);
   rangeExpWidth = Math.log10(range[1]) - Math.log10(range[0]);
} else if (range[0] === 0) {
   exponentAdjust = -3;
   rangeExpWidth = Math.log10(range[1]) - exponentAdjust;
} else {
   rangeExpWidth = Math.log10(range[1]) - Math.log10(range[0]);
}

// simplified case

for (i = 0; i <= rangeExpWidth; i++) {
   console.log(i + exponentAdjust, Math.pow(10, i + exponentAdjust).toFixed(2));
}

console.log('--------------');

// as used in graph, to draw the markers

width = 500;
markerXCount = 10;
markerXInterval = width / markerXCount;
console.log(markerXInterval);

for (x = 0; x <= width; x++) {
   if (x % markerXInterval === 0) {
      exponent = ((x / width) * rangeExpWidth) + exponentAdjust;
      frequency = Math.pow(10, exponent);
      console.log(x / markerXInterval, 'exp:', exponent, 'value:', Math.pow(10, exponent));
   }
}
```

The only way I see, so far, without adding too much complexity, is simply defining zero as 10^-1 and then rounding as appropriate, though that may potentially introduces other issues?

Comment: Have you tried replacing 0 with 0.00001 or something that suits your precision?

Comment: `0` is at negative infinity on a logarithmic scale. Therefore, it can't really be plotted.

Comment: Pick a range on the negative y-axis that's meaningful for you and choose x accordingly.

Comment: @Lyes BEN I have, though I'll have to add logic to skip certain negative exponents ranges. Was hoping there was something more elegant or a day different way of approaching the problem?